How to execute a function without a class using reflection, given only a string with its name?
A function is easy to call if it is a member of a class:
package com.example

class MyClass {
    fun myFunction() : String {
        return "result"
    }
}

val myClass = Class.forName("com.example::MyClass").kotlin
val myFunction = myClass.functions.firstOrNull { it.name == "myFunction" }
val result = myFunction?.call()

But what if the function com.example::myFunction is without a class?
package com.example

fun myFunction() : String {
    return "result"
}

Condition: file name unknown.
In JVM there will still be a class, it is the file name with the Kt suffix.

Not possible if file name is unknown. There could be multiple such functions declared at the top level of different files. How do you want to differentiate between them? If you assume there is only one such function, then I suppose you could just search all the classes in the classpath.

You cannot create two identical functions in the same package, even if the files are different.

Classes can be dynamically loaded so that’s only true at compile-time. So you assume that the function you want to call is in the same package and there is no other function with the same name, and that it has no parameters?

I think I got you, the file name is an important parameter when loading a function... Thank you.

You are compiling both files at the same time. What I meant was that you can compile the files separately but load them into the same JVM instance. In any case, are my assumptions correct? You are not dynamically loading classes, and you know the package name in which the functions are declared?

You are right, as long as Kotlin depends on the JVM ClassLoader, the filename is a mandatory value when dynamically loading.

Why do you want to do this?  Reflection is a strong code smell: slow, ugly, fragile, and insecure.  It's a necessary evil for frameworks, plugins, and build tools, but for general application coding there's almost always a better approach.

Assuming that you know which package the global function is in, you first need to find all the Kotlin file facade classes (the classes with a Kt suffix) in that package. This can be done with the Reflections library, or you can try one of the ways here.
You can find which classes are Kotlin file facade classes by reading the kotlin.Metadata annotation. Single file facades have a kind of 2, and multi-file facades have a kind of 4. I would suggest using kotlinx-metadata if you also need other metadata-related things.
fun main() {
    val reflections = Reflections(
        ConfigurationBuilder()
            .forPackage("com.example")
    )
    callTopLevelMethodsWithName("someMethod", reflections)
}

fun callTopLevelMethodsWithName(name: String, reflections: Reflections) {
    for (kotlinClass in reflections.get(Scanners.TypesAnnotated.of(Metadata::class.java).`as`(Class::class.java))) {
        val metadata = KotlinClassMetadata.readStrict(kotlinClass.getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java))
        if (metadata is KotlinClassMetadata.FileFacade || metadata is KotlinClassMetadata.MultiFileClassFacade) {
            kotlinClass.methods.find { it.name == name }?.let {
                it.invoke(null)
                return
            }
        }

//        // if you don't use kotlinx-metadata
//        val metadata = kotlinClass.getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java)
//
//        if (metadata.kind == 2 || metadata.kind == 4) {
//            // ...
//        }
    }
}

Note that you need to pass the JVM name of the method you want to call to this method. If you want to use the Kotlin name instead, you'd need to read the metadata to find the corresponding Java method name:
// the for loop body would look something like this
val metadata = KotlinClassMetadata.readStrict(kotlinClass.getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java))
val kmPackage = when(metadata) {
    is KotlinClassMetadata.FileFacade -> metadata.kmPackage
    is KotlinClassMetadata.MultiFileClassPart -> metadata.kmPackage
    else -> null
} ?: continue
val javaMethodName = kmPackage.functions.find { it.name == name }?.signature?.name
if (javaMethodName != null) {
    kotlinClass.getMethod(javaMethodName)?.let {
        it.invoke(null)
        return
    }
}


call the myFunction from reflection like this
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredFunctions
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaMethod
fun main() {
    // Load the class corresponding to the file
    val clazz = Class.forName("com.example.MyFile")
    
    // Find the function by name using reflection
    val function = clazz.kotlin.declaredFunctions.firstOrNull { it.name == "myFunction" }
    
    //  all the function if it's found
    val result = function?.call()
    
       println(result) 
}


This is only possible if you know the file name. Only you forgot about the Kt suffix (MyFileKt).
